# Reformatting the output in a perl script

Tags: perl

I'm currently using the suggested transformation of an gnmap file from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352291)

```
$ perl -ne '$host = $1 if /^Host: (\S+)/; while(m,(\d+)/open,g) 
    { print "$host\t$1\n" } ' < nmap.out
```

Sadly, I need the output not in the format:

```
IP_A port1
IP_A port2
IP_A port3
IP_B port1
```

I need one line per host, followed by all ports that are open on this host. i.e.:

```
IP_A;port1;port2,port3,...
IP_B;port1;port2,port3,...
```

Can someone give me a hint on how to manipulate the code? Sorry for this absolute n00b-question, but I have never worked with Perl before and can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
perl -ne '@ports = m<(\d+)/open>g or next; m/^Host: (\S+)/ or next; $"=","; print "$1;@ports\n";' <nmap.out
```

which yields

```
10.0.0.99;135,139,445,554,10243
192.168.0.1;135,139,445,10243
```

I have (perhaps wrongly!) assumed that your desired output is the IP, a semicolon, and a comma-delimited list of ports. If you require a semicolon after the first port, and commas after the second (and subsequent) ports, it's harder.

Comment: Can also merge the first two statements, `@p = m<(\d+)/open>g and /^Host: (\S+)/ or next;` (if you wish) or even string them all up `@p=... and /.../ and $"=";", say "$1;@p"'`

Comment: (need `-E` for feature `say`, instead of `-e`, like `perl -wnE'...'`.  Or `CORE::say`)

Comment: That's why I used `print`. My initial iteration had `-nE` and `say`, but I decided to keep my response simple rather than introducing "...but you have to have at least Perl 5.10 to do this." That **should** not a problem these days, but you never know.

Comment: "_That's why I used print..._", I thought so and then I thought I'd mention it in comments :). These were literally "comments," not suggestions to change the answer.  (It's also reasonable to avoid peppering one-liners with `-E` since it enables everything and so is likely not future proof...)

Answer (score 2):

The script by [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) you found can easily be amended to output one line per host followed by all of its open ports.

The key is to capture all of our ports in [list context](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.38.0/perlretut#Global-matching). To print the list's content as a comma-separated list, use [join](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join).

```
perl -nle '
$host = $1 if /^Host: (\S+)/;
if ( @ports=( m,(\d+)/open,g ) ) {
  print "$host: ", join ",", @ports;
  @ports=();
}
' < nmap.out
```

This produces output like:

```
10.0.0.99: 135,139,445,554,10243
192.168.0.1: 135,139,445,10243
```